# java default date formate equivalent in objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

When we get date in java (`new Date()`) the format is "Tue May 13 13:37:06 UTC 2014". How can i get this format in objective c?

Comment: Can you not just use `[NSDate date];`?

Comment: No i need same formate.

Comment: Ok so have you thought about `NSDateFormatter`?

Answer (score 0):

this is how you get….. :)

```
 NSDate *newDate = [NSDate date];

 NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

 [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"]; // set here your own

 NSString *currentDate = [formatter stringFromDate:newDate];
```